# PHImageManager fetch request take long time to response

Tags: swift, phimagemanager

When I call this function to get the last image from photos, UI is blocked for around 4 seconds. Any idea for that?

This is my code

```
import SwiftUI
import Photos

class GalleryManager: NSObject {}

extension GalleryManager {
    func loadLastImageThumb(_ completion: @escaping (UIImage) -> ()) {
        let imgManager = PHImageManager.default()
        let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
        fetchOptions.fetchLimit = 1
        fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key:"creationDate", ascending: true)]
        
        let fetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: PHAssetMediaType.image, options: fetchOptions)
        
        if let last = fetchResult.lastObject {
            let size = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
            let options = PHImageRequestOptions()
            options.resizeMode = .fast
            options.deliveryMode = .fastFormat
            options.isSynchronous = true
            
            imgManager.requestImage(for: last, targetSize: size, contentMode: PHImageContentMode.aspectFill, options: options, resultHandler: { (image, _) in
                if let image = image {
                    completion(image)
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing is wrong and illegal. You are saying `options.isSynchronous = true` when your code runs on the main thread. Just delete that line and deal with the image as it arrives (possibly multiple times).

Comment: Of course I tried with  `options.isSynchronous = true` and `false` as well. After check logs, I saw slow issue only happen when I turned off photo access permission.

Comment: The only code I know about is the code you show me. You showed me wrong code and I told you what was wrong with it. Read the docs! There is a huge note on this page telling you not to do what you're doing: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phimagerequestoptions/1616945-issynchronous

Comment: Also `import SwiftUI` is wrong. This is not SwiftUI.

Comment: But you see, I am using `UIImage` type in code, so I need to import `SwiftUI` or `UIKit` for that type.

Comment: Yes, so it should be UIKit. Do _you_ see?